# How can I to add relative path to PIE.htc file?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have in my CSS file the rules related with PIE.htc file, the border-radius is working for IE8 but this not working for IE7, checking my web console in the browser this is the output:

// When the browser is IE8 (this is the output of the web console from my IE browser)
behavior:  url(css/PIE.htc);

//when the browser is IE7 (this is the output of the web console from my IE browser)
behavior: url(./css/css/PIE.htc);

```
.circle{
    border: 1px solid #696;
    padding: 60px 0;
    text-align: center; width: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #EEFF99;
    behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/ie-fix.min.css?v=1.0.4">     

<!-- html tag with the border radius -->

<div class="circle"></div>
```

I can not to fix this, how can I to add a relative path for PIE.htc file that allow to work for IE7 and IE8??

Note: My PIE.htc file is in the same folder with CSS file

css/ie-fix.min.css
css/PIE.htc

thanks for you help! merry christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

Comment: Not work, applying this not work for IE8 too, Sorry =(

Comment: Thanks for you help, fix this include using '/' by example url(/PIE/PIE.htc); and the problem is solved, thanks!.